# Error in Curl request with response in Controller

Tags: controllers, php-7, curl-request

I'm trying to get curl response from js (cc-method.js) file. The curl call code is in controller file `domain.com/frontname/section/index`. Below is the code,

```
public function execute()
    {
 // create a new cURL resource
                $ch = curl_init();

                $data = '{"merchantIdentifier":"'.PRODUCTION_MERCHANTIDENTIFIER.'", "domainName":"'.PRODUCTION_DOMAINNAME.'", "displayName":"'.PRODUCTION_DISPLAYNAME.'"}';

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $validation_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, PRODUCTION_CERTIFICATE_PATH);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, PRODUCTION_CERTIFICATE_KEY);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, PRODUCTION_CERTIFICATE_KEY_PASS);
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2');
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256,ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                // close cURL resource, and free up system resources

                return $result;
}
```

I'm getting the response but with error too. Below is the response,

```
{"epochTimestamp":1581515057355,"expiresAt":1581518657355,"merchantSe .........................
```

error:

```
Exception: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/........Index.php
```

It is pointing the line of `$result = curl_exec($ch);`.

I have tried to disable the php error and warning but that time there is no response. The response always coming with error only. Any hint will be helpfull for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `curl_exec` will print the response, that's causing the `output started` error when you return the content.

Try to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` curl option. This will store the result in your `$result` var.